# Hibernate creates a lot of threads and freeze

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm building an application that reads information from a log file and saves those data into a database. The information is a set of packages with some users added to the package, like below:

```
Package: (Total: 14, Used: 11)
    CSHC, 11/11
    CTQ8, 11/11
    CTQ8, 11/11
```

Every time I end reading one package from the log I make a call to save the package into the database. The problem is that after saving the 4th package, the application freezes. Using the Debug I saw that the hibernate is creating a single session to each saves operation and not closing it after each save, and I think that is the problem, but I'm not sure if that is the cause of the problem.

```
boolean erasePack = false;
Package pack = new Package();
//System.out.println("Zerei? "+ petrelLicensesInUse);
while (i < reportContent.size()){
    phrase = reportContent.get(i);
    if(erasePack){
        pack = new Package();
        erasePack = false;
    }


    if(phrase.contains(Constants.licenseUsageIdentifier)){
        licenseUsage = true;
        licenseUser = false;
        licenseIssued = phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.totalLicenseAvailableId) + 10),phrase.indexOf(Constants.endLicensesIssued));
        licenseUsed = phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.totalLicenseUsedId) + 12),phrase.indexOf(Constants.endLicensesUsed));
        licenseIssuedNum = Integer.parseInt(licenseIssued);
        licenseUsedNum = Integer.parseInt(licenseUsed);
        licenseUsageList.add(phrase.replaceAll(";  Total of ", ", Used: ").replaceAll("Users of ", "")
                .replaceAll(" licenses issued", "").replaceAll(" licenses in use", "").replaceAll("Total of", "Total:")
                .replaceAll(" license in use", "").replaceAll(" license issued", "").replace("  ", " "));
        if(licenseUsedNum != 0){
            pack.setUsers(new ArrayList<PbrUser>());
        }
    }

    if(phrase.contains(Constants.licenseUserIdentifier)){
        licenseUsage = false;
        licenseUser = true;
        currPckg =  phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.licenseUserIdentifier) + 1),phrase.indexOf(Constants.licenseUserIdentifier + " "));
        version = phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.version) + 3),phrase.indexOf(Constants.endVersion));
        vendorDaemon = phrase.substring((phrase.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
        pack.setNamePackage(currPckg);
        pack.setVersion(version);
        pack.setVendorDaemon(vendorDaemon);
        pack.setNumberOfPackageLicenses(licenseIssuedNum);

        //PackageController.create(pack);
    }


    if(licenseUser && phrase.contains(Constants.userStartDateId)){
        //System.out.println(phrase.indexOf(Constants.userStartDateId));
        currDate = transformDate(phrase.substring((phrase.indexOf(Constants.userStartDateId)+Constants.userStartDateId.length()),phrase.length()));
        //System.out.println(phrase.substring(Constants.spaceUntilUser +1,phrase.length()).indexOf(" "));
        currName = phrase.substring(Constants.spaceUntilUser, (Constants.spaceUntilUser + phrase.substring(Constants.spaceUntilUser +1,phrase.length()).indexOf(" ")+1));
        PbrUser pbrUser = new PbrUser(currName);
        //PbrUserController.create(pbrUser);
        reportMetadataList.add(new ReportMetadata(currName, currPckg, currDate));
        if(licenseUsedNum != 0){
            //PbrUser pbrUser = new PbrUser(currName);
            pack.getUsers().add(pbrUser);
        }
        contSave++;
    }

    if(licenseUser && contSave == licenseUsedNum){
        PackageController.create(pack);
        contSave=0;
        erasePack = true;
    }

        i++;
}
```

Insertion code:

```
static protected void insert(Object object) {
    Transaction tx = null;
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(object);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
            try {
                // Second try catch as the rollback could fail as well
                tx.rollback();
            } catch (HibernateException e1) {
                logger.debug("Error rolling back transaction");
            }
            // throw again the first exception
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Hibernate Session factory:

```
public class SessionFactoryUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    /**
     * disable constructor to guaranty a single instance
     */
    private SessionFactoryUtil() {
    }

    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
          Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
          configuration.configure();
          serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
          sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
          return sessionFactory;
        }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return createSessionFactory();
    }

  /**
   * Opens a session and will not bind it to a session context
   * @return the session
   */
    public Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    /**
   * Returns a session from the session context. If there is no session in the context it opens a session,
   * stores it in the context and returns it.
     * This factory is intended to be used with a hibernate.cfg.xml
     * including the following property <property
     * name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> This would return
     * the current open session or if this does not exist, will create a new
     * session
     * 
     * @return the session
     */
    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

  /**
   * closes the session factory
   */
    public static void close(){
        if (sessionFactory != null)
            sessionFactory.close();
        sessionFactory = null;

    }
}
```

Comment: In `insert(Object object)` you must use `try{}finally{close()}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your call to `SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory()` is not a singleton.  It creates a new Session object every time.  Modify that method to truly be a singleton so that it only creates a new instance the first time it's called.

You will still have the issue of not properly closing that session when your code is done so you will have to call `session.close()` at the end of your application.

**EDIT**

The first thing to change is the call to getSessionFactory() to return the same instance:

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    //return createSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Now we just have to make sure the `sessionFactory` is created before any calls to `getSessionFactory()`.   There are lots of ways to do this, one of the more easier ways is to use a static block which will be called at class load time (the first time any of your code calls any SessionFactoryUtil methods)

```
public class SessionFactoryUtil {

   ...fields declared the same 

   static{
         createSessionFactory();
   }

  ...
}
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't be sure, but it's probably a good idea to make `createSessionFactory()` private so no one else can overwrite your sessionFactory instance.

Comment: Im sorry, I am new to hibernate, and I do not know how to modify to be a singleton. How can I do that?

Comment: I've tried to use this solution, but now it freezes after the first save.

Comment: Now I tryed to use the hibernate.c3p0 to manage the poool size and stuff, and it's giving, after the 4th insertion into the database, an warning saying:

ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:730 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@73cc7a69 -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]